# Hide implementation file in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

By holding command button and click on a class name I can reach it's implementation. But in case of the file of framework we can't. like if I hold command button and click on `NSString`
I can reach `@interface NSString : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding>`.
But now if I do the same thing on `NSString` again it'll not take me to it's implementation.

So No my question is I want to the same thing, I want to hide my all the implementation. How do I do that?

Comment: Why? From who? Release a library.

Comment: @wain Actually my client want the source code. so any how I have to that.

Comment: If your client pays for sources - you should provide them. It's general practice, however. If he doesn't pay... Well, this question maybe isn't off-topic on stackoverflow, but there are too much cases here that do not relate to programming

Answer (score 0):

Apple achieves this by creating frameworks:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html

You could also create a static library:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

Comment: I have followed both of them but it's not working. My `.a` file is in red colour and it's not in `finder` also.

Comment: Unfortunately I have never build a library or framework myself, so I cant't help you anymore then those two guides can.